# Clock server is not allowed to request view anymore since CSRF Fix / plone.protect 3

Tags: plone, csrf, plone-4.x

Is clock server not anymore a recommended way to do scheduled tasks?
Any hint how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred approach is to use a separate instance to handle cron jobs.
I keep that instance out of the publication stack, so it does not receive requests from outside.
For this reason CSRF is not a threat for that instance.
In the "cron instance" you can safely set the environment variable PLONE_CSRF_DISABLED value to true without bothering about CSRF at all.

In a zeo buildout this translates to something like:

```
[instance-cron]
recipe = collective.recipe.zope2cluster
<= instance-settings
environment-vars +=
    PLONE_CSRF_DISABLED true
```

Comment: Depending on how many cronjobs you want to run how often, you'd not even need to keep that instance up all the time, you could start it in the cronjob. It won't save you from outside attack, but it might mostly save you from accidentally doing experiments on that instance, forgetting it writes into prod.

Answer (score 3):

You are probably calling a view periodically so you can read how to perform write-on-read from the plone.protect documentation.
The section you are looking for is probably "[Marking the entire request as safe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.protect#marking-the-entire-request-as-safe)".

In that way you can mark the request as "safe" for performing write.